# Website gamification what achievements?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, user-behavior

I run a website with news and stories and I want to improve the user experience and pageviews per session with a gamification. What should I add to my current approach along the achievements?

http://eywow.com/a/test.php

Comment: You are most likely looking at a user account, profile etc. If it’s a ‘news’ website, do you believe users will go the extra mile to create a profile, an account etc.. to gain points. As gurvinder72 rightly points out, what do they get in return ? what’s the incentive? I am not sure you can increase page views just by having points. There is something missing in the model here.. please elaborate.A ‘context’ would be very helpful..Please let us know what the website’s targeted audience is, any more info etc.

Comment: We are not a website review service. we are here to solve specific UX issues. Just asking 'how is the gamification on my website' isn't a question that benefits anyone other than yourself, so it not suitable for this site. At best it is unsuitable, at worst it is spam.

Comment: Why do you think that gamification will improve the user experience and page views?

Answer (score 1):

Few points to ponder upon

1. Points are not going to help if they don't mean anything by itself.
   For example, a user can help his/her resume by making a lot of
   points on SO. **How do you think points will help your readers?**
2. What all features do you want to give to your readers? Are some of
   them paid/free? **Can user unlock some premium features by earning
   points and referrals/shares?**
3. Your points system must not look like an advertisement to use your
   own site. **User should naturally explore your site.** His points
   should gradually increase and then decrease if he continues to
   explore the same topics of interest. If you want to make them browse
   more, you must reward them for exploring new things.
4. **Build a community of your readers**. Take their comments/feedback on stories. Nothing ensures future visits from readers more than
   this.

I don't know what new experience you are offering to your readers so I don't know if I can suggest further.